# Not Supported exception in the download of file with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, file

I'd like to download a file in my ASP.NET application. I used this snippet:

```
try
{
    string s = fichier.GetFichierUrlById(_id);
    Response.ContentType = "application/" + Path.GetExtension(s); 
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + s);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/"+s));
    Response.End();
}
catch { }
```

In this example, I have the file `setup.exe`, and I get an exception like `The format of the given path is not supported.`

What is the cause of this exception? How can I fix the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of S, and hence, the return value of "Server.MapPath("~/Downloads/"+s).

You might have some invalid characters in S which blow things out maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`TransmitFile` would assume that there is a physical file in the downloads sub folder.

If that is not the case, then you'll need to do something like write the data into the output stream yourself.